# Mean function output not separated by commas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

That's my code:

```
array = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
axis1_mean = np.mean(array,axis = 0)
print(axis1_mean)
```

That's the output:

```
[3. 4. 5.]
```

I need the output separated by commas, is there an easy way to do so?
I found [in the documentation of Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) that the output should be separated by commas. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Why?  The result is a `numpy` array.  That's the normal way it prints!  The fuller `repr` print includes commas.  LIsts also display with commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the CONTENT of your data from the REPRESENTATION of your data.  Your data is a list of three floating point numbers.  There are no commas, no brackets, and no decimal points in your data.

If you need to PRESENT your data in a specific way, then it is up to you to do that.  What you're seeing is the way numpy presents data by default.  If you want commas, you have to add them:

```
print( "[" + (",".join(str(f) for f in axis1_mean)) + "]")
```

Comment: I don't think he is trying to print the output with commas. I think he just has a misconseption because in the documentation they are not using print().

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but he did literally say "I need the output separated by commas"  This content vs representation thing is an extremely common confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that will help but they are indeed separated by commas (just like the documentation) if you look at them in a jupyter notebook or execute them. But the print() method prints it differently (without the commas). And it has nothing to do with the mean function itself.

Like this:

```
>>> np.array([5, 5, 5])
```

Output:

```
array([5, 5, 5])
```

But with print:

```
>>> print(np.array([5, 5, 5]))
```

Output:

```
[5 5 5]
```

If what you need is to "print" them seperated by commas then @Tim's answer will do the job

Comment: They are not separated by commas.  There are no commas in that data.

Comment: He is saying ( I found in the documentation of Numpy that the output should be separated by commas.)
In the documentation what they have is this: 
```>>> np.mean(a, axis=1)```
```array([1.5, 3.5])
```

Comment: Yes, but you said "they are indeed separated by commas".  No, they aren't.  The data are individual objects.  They can be PRINTED with or without commas, but the array itself is not a string and contains no punctuation.  This is a VITALLY important point that many beginning programmers do not understand.

Comment: Since he did accept your answer I think there is no point to discuss now. But from his question what was apparent is that he wanted to see the same answer as in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print them with the commas and the brackets.

You can use:

```
print(str(list(axis1_mean)))
```